# React-native StackNavigator disable going back

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am developing an app which requires a user to login to get access the features of the app. Once the user logs in, and is redirected to the User stack , I don't want them to be able to go back to the login screen in any way.

On login success I used:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('User')
```

I followed authentication flows in the docs on the react-navigation website but once i press back the user is able to go back to the login screen.

I have separated my screens into two different stacks, User and Guest, and I also have the loading screen that is shown in the documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow (I am using version 4.3.3)

```
const Navigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Guest: guest,
    User: user
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

Is there any way to prevent the user from going back to the guest stack? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StackNavigator obviously works like a stack. So, if you want to prevent users being able to navigate back, you have to clear the stack.
If you are using simple routes, you can use [replace](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-actions/#replace)

`this.props.navigation.replace('User')`

This would replace your current route (AuthLoading) with route User. Earlier routes would stay in the stack.

If your User and Guest itself are again nested navigators, I'd recommend using [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-actions/#reset).

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'User' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

This would wipe the whole stack and replaces it with your new stack, which you can build directly up inside the actions-array.